# How to setup Python socket server correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I recently started learning Python but I came across a question. Why does my while True loop stops when I do socket.accept()

My code does that keeps printing 'HEY!!':

```
import socket


host = "0.0.0.0"  #<- Not the real port and ip, I have working ones...
port = 1234

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

while True:

    print("HEY!!")

    '''
    connection, adress = s.accept()
    print("Got connection from: '" + str(adress[0]) + ":" + str(adress[1]) + "'")
    '''
```

My code that only prints 'HEY!!' once:

```
import socket


host = "0.0.0.0"  #<- Not the real port and ip, I have working ones...
port = 1234

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

while True:

    print("HEY!!")

    connection, adress = s.accept()
    print("Got connection from: '" + str(adress[0]) + ":" + str(adress[1]) + "'")
```

And how can I solve that it keeps printing 'HEY!!' but also let the socket work?

Thanks for reading!

**UPDATE:**
It is working now, I am using threading to achieve it.
Do you have the same problem? -> Google: "Multiple while true loops threading python"
**Thanks for everyone that helped me!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does my while True loop stops when I do socket.accept()

`accept` is a blocking operation. It waits until a client connects. It continues after the client has been connected and returns the socket for the new client connection.

> My code that only prints 'HEY!!' once:

It will print `HEY!!` more than once if clients connect to your server and thus the blocking `accept` returns.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! So this means that 'HEY' will be printed after there is a socket connected and then it all starts again with waiting for a connection. Is it possible to have 2 different while loops? 1 that checks if a socket is connected and 1 to print out hey? Thanks again.

Comment: @Banjer_HD: One can use threads to have multiple while loops in the same program. But this is a different question.